# Is there a way to optimize space in this DP program?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

Problem Statement:

A palindrome is a symmetrical string, that is, a string read identically from left to right as well as from right to left. You are to write a program which, given a string, determines the minimal number of characters to be inserted into the string in order to obtain a palindrome. As an example, by inserting 2 characters, the string "Ab3bd" can be transformed into a palindrome ("dAb3bAd" or "Adb3bdA"). However, inserting fewer than 2 characters does not produce a palindrome.

Input

The first line contains one integer: the length of the input string N, 3≤N≤5000. The second line contains one string with length N. The string is formed from uppercase letters from ‘A’ to ‘Z’, lowercase letters from ‘a’ to ‘z’ and digits from ‘0’ to ‘9’. Uppercase and lowercase letters are to be considered distinct.

Output

The first line contains one integer, which is the desired minimal number.

Link to problem => http://www.spoj.com/problems/IOIPALIN/

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

long  memo[5010][5010];
string s;
 long int n;
long  solve(long  i,long  j){

if(memo[i][j]!=-1){
return memo[i][j];
}
if(i>=j)
 return 0;
 if(s[i]==s[j])
   return solve(i+1,j-1);
 return memo[i][j]= min(solve(i,j-1)+1,solve(i+1,j)+1);
}

int  main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
long int  n ;
cin>>n;
cin>>s;
memset(memo,-1,sizeof(memo));

long int a = solve(0,n-1);
cout << a << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am getting "time limit exceeded" for this code. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Just a note, "DP program" is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well being a programmer its a bad practice to ask directly the solution to the question. I won't provide you with the exact code, but I will help you solve the problem.

To solve this an n^2 approach is needed. Dynamic programming is what you need. To achieve that create a string `rev_str` that is reverse of `str`. Now see the following pseudo code.

```
for(i = 0 to n) 
    for(j = 0 to n)
       if(i = 0 or j = 0) dp[j][1] = 0;
       else if(str[i - 1] = rev_str[j - 1]) dp[j][1] = dp[j - 1][0] + 1;
       else dp[j][1] = max(dp[j][0], dp[j - 1][1];
    for (j = 0 to n) dp[j][0] = dp[j][1];
```

your answer will be `n - dp[n][0]`.

Basically what we are trying to do is at every step we are finding the maximum number of characters that match from `str` to `rev_str`. Those remaining will be needed to be added. Thus giving an answer.

Comment: complexity of my solution is also O(n^2) . isn't it ?

Comment: In `min(solve(i,j-1)+1,solve(i+1,j)+1);` statement you are creating two branches and solving for both of them. So in worst cast if this statement is executing everytime you will be doubling your execution and thus complexity of O(2^n).

Comment: But I have used memoization . Won't it reduce time complexity ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't see it.

Comment: Well maybe its giving you TLE because when using memo its value is most of the time -1 meaning you aren't actually using its value. Try to Dry run that please.